# Border bottom leaves unwanted space at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I want a border bottom to run below my button the entire length of the div. However, the border bottom creates an unwanted space that doesnt go away even with 0 padding, 0 margin and 0 height.

Here's the jsfiddle
:
http://jsfiddle.net/z0Lzeppj/3/

Heres the html

```
<body>

    <!--Header-->
    <div class="header"></div>
    <!--End Header-->


    <!--Container-->
    <div class="container">

        <!--Left-->
        <div class="left"></div>
        <!-- End Left -->


        <!--Right-->
        <div class="right"></div>
        <!-- end Right -->


        <!--Center-->
        <div class="center">

         <!--Feed Content-->
         <div id="feed-content">
         <div id="networkfeed" class="feedpagetab activefeed"> 


 <input type="checkbox" id="filterbutton" role="button">
         <label for="filterbutton" onclick=""><span class="filterswitch" id="show">Show Me</span><span class="filterswitch" id="hide">Hide Me</span> 
          </label>

 <div class="borderline"></div>

            <div id="contentSection">
            <div id="content2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ius an dolorum lucilius sensibus, et sint graeco nec. Iudico atomorum eam eu. Nec equidem conceptam id. Cum velit viris voluptua an. Sea eu harum eirmod eloquentiam, quaestio complectitur voluptatibus in nam, an dicam platonem adolescens has. Te usu esse idque, no modo tractatos sed. Vero audire sapientem an sit, homero recteque pri in, vis at vidit admodum. Ex quo doctus eleifend contentiones, vis odio mucius tritani ut. Id cetero nostrud dissentiunt mel. Docendi scaevola vis ei. Vel et ponderum electram expetendis, cum cu quaestio definitionem, etiam ponderum vix ei. Ut his feugait assentior philosophia, atqui definitionem at mei. Liber sonet dictas ea has, nec odio fabellas ei. Vel oratio quodsi in, duo minim admodum ea. Pri id dolorum indoctum, vim at alia tritani. No pro esse error solet, vix quis prodesset ei. Tollit accommodare vis at, sed in tamquam prompta dolorem. Nam solum definitionem an, dicta nostrum adversarium ne nec. Eu docendi nominavi similique pri. Qui an natum tamquam, dictas invenire mei id. Cu omittam insolens rationibus ius, dicunt inciderint cum ea. Est vero dolorem et, assum antiopam mea ne. Te vel choro audiam, eum equidem nostrum ex. Ea nam offendit definitiones. In etiam debitis similique cum. Ius regione incorrupte te, utinam ceteros an has, omnium concludaturque cum eu. Eu sumo adhuc ius. Quo choro quodsi latine an. Nonumy deleniti duo ex, fastidii menandri accusata ut mea, ad minimum omnesque quo. Cum in molestiae mediocritatem. Partiendo voluptaria cum te. Illud reque convenire duo et, audiam denique consectetuer mei te. Bonorum fabellas interpretaris mel ad. Eu sanctus nominavi ius, oratio vocibus indoctum ea eos. Et nisl doming vituperatoribus vis. Ullum percipit inciderint ei duo, ex usu stet essent. Quis errem legere ex quo, usu ludus decore ut, vix cetero convenire honestatis et. Mucius nusquam platonem per et, cu mei nibh erant inermis. Ne quo erant commodo sadipscing. Mei delenit tibique aliquando no, vim ex omnis vocibus scriptorem. Reque aperiam hendrerit et per, sit suas vivendo corrumpit in. Ius ei falli doming periculis. Nam quis iuvaret at. Impedit minimum similique ei pri, graeco interpretaris eu ius, dolor probatus scribentur in qui. Duo aliquam omittam voluptaria no. Vel enim hendrerit persecuti ne. Sed no idque fastidii neglegentur. Everti accusamus deterruisset eos ut, an sea feugiat alienum rationibus. Duo ex graece gloriatur, lorem appetere inimicus sed eu, autem sanctus in ius. No lorem altera qualisque eum, id eum labore necessitatibus, sit no diceret pertinax partiendo. At pri hinc solet voluptatum, ut debitis intellegam vix. Decore ridens comprehensam sea id, ius aperiam delicatissimi no. Quas molestie ei his, in has augue equidem adipisci.
             </div><!--End Content-->             
             </div><!--End Content Section-->



          </div> <!--End Network feed-->
        </div><!--End Feed Content-->
    </div><!--End Center-->


    <!--Footer-->
    <div id="footer">
        <ul id="footerlist">
            <li id="terms"><a class="termsbutton" href="#termspop">Terms</a>
            </li>
            <li id="privacy"><a href="">Privacy</a>

            </li>
            <li id="contact"><a href="">Contact</a>

            </li>
            <li id="help"><a href="">Help</a>

            </li>
            <li id="careers"><a href="">Careers</a>

            </li>
            <li id="developers"><a href="">Developers</a>

            </li>
            <li id="advertisers"><a href="">Advertisers</a>

            </li>
            <li id="about"><a href="">About</a>

            </li>
            <li id="cookies"><a href="">Cookies</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--End Footer-->

    </div><!--End Container-->
</body>
```

And the css

```
html {
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
body {
    background-color:blue;
    min-height:300px;
}
.center {
    overflow:hidden;
    min-height:100%;
    float:none;
    background-color:#FFF;
    color:#999;
    position:relative;
}
#contentSection {
    overflow-y:scroll; 
    position:absolute; bottom:0;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green;
}
/* ------------------Header ----------------*/
 .header {
    width:100%;
    height:5%;
    color:#000;
    min-width:768px;
    min-height:60px;
    position:relative;
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/* ------------------Container ----------------*/
 .container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width:100%;
    min-width: 768px;
    position:relative;
    height:90%;
    min-height:495px;
    max-height:90%;
}
/*----- Left -----*/
 .left {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    text-align:center;
    min-height:360px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    min-width:153px;
    max-height:95%;
    max-width:170px;
}
/*----- Right -----*/
 .right {
    float:right;
    width:20%;
    text-align:center;
    min-height:440px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    max-height:95%;
    max-width:230px;
    min-width:160px;
}
/* ------------------Footer ----------------*/
 #footerlist li {
    float:left;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Arial;
    margin-left:10px;
}
#footerlist li a:link {
    color:#CCC;
    text-decoration:none;
}
/* unvisited link */
 #footerlist li a:visited {
    color:#CCC;
    text-decoration:none;
}
/* visited link */
 #footerlist li a:hover {
    color:#F90;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
/* mouse over link */
 #footerlist li a:active {
    color:#f90;
    text-decoration:none;
}
/* selected link */
 #footerlist li a {
    color:#000;
}
#footerlist li a :link {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
/* unvisited link */
 #terms #privacy #contact #help #careers #developers #advertisers #about #cookies:visited {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
/* visited link */
 div#footer {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    clear: both;
    height:2%;
}
#footerlist {
    display:table;
    margin-left:auto;
    min-width:650px;
    line-height:24px;
    margin-right:auto;
    bottom:0px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
/*----- Show me Button-----*/

#filterbutton[type=checkbox] {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
[for="filterbutton"] {
    position: absolute;
    top:4px;
    padding: 0;
    left: 5%;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #555;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #DDD;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, "Sans Serif";
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px #FFF;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px #FFF;
    background: #EEE;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #DDD 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #F9F9F9), color-stop(100%, #DDD));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #DDD 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #DDD 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #DDD 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#F9F9F9', endColorstr='#DDD', GradientType=0);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #DDD 100%); 
}
[for="filterbutton"]:hover {
    color: #444444;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-color: #BBB;
    background: #CCC;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #CCC 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #F9F9F9), color-stop(100%, #CCC));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #CCC 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #CCC 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #CCC 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#F9F9F9', endColorstr='#CCC', GradientType=0);
}
[for="filterbutton"] span.filterswitch:last-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#filterbutton[type=checkbox]:checked {
    color:#FFA317;
}

#filterbutton[type=checkbox]:checked ~[for="filterbutton"] span.filterswitch:first-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#filterbutton[type=checkbox]:checked ~[for="filterbutton"] span.filterswitch:last-of-type {
    color:#3CC;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}

#content {
    margin: 0; display:inline-block;
    position:relative; bottom:0;
    padding: 0; 
    height:170px;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.borderline {
    width:100%; display:block;
    border-bottom:#000 solid 1px;
    height:37px; top:0; 
}
```

Comment: It is really something you want do with `#contentSection` a `position: absolute;` if not take that one out it works perfect.

Comment: are you looking for something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/z0Lzeppj/4/

Comment: Gonna have to agree with Benjamin here.  This layout you want to achieve is not complex, and you are making it complex..  Position: absolute; isn't needed to achieve what you want here...

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position:absolute;` from `#contentSection` that works

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z0Lzeppj/5/)**

Comment: It fixes his issue with the border, but now the box has too much height.  I believe the purpose is for the box to be a small window.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that the white space at the bottom of the border is now at the bottom of the green scrolling div.

Answer (score 0):

Your border bottom element has an absolute height of 37 px, decrease this to the size of the border line if you don't want such a big div.

Comment: Did you even bother to test this?  Doing so breaks his layout.  There are more fundamental problems here. 

http://jsfiddle.net/z0Lzeppj/6/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the:

> position: absolute;

in the `#contentSection`

and add a

> height: 100% !important;

hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution is to remove **height:37px** and replace it with **padding-bottom:37px**
http://jsfiddle.net/e0kpfpud/

```
.borderline {
    width:100%; display:block;
    border-bottom:#000 solid 1px;
    padding-bottom:37px; top:0; 
}
```

also remove position:absolute; from #contentSection credit to Benji

Answer (score -1):

You need to update the css, just remove the height, min-height from .left, .right and .container

Comment: Remove da height on what and do the things to da what? Herp derp?

Are we talking * {height: 0; padding: 20px 10px; }

Answer (score -1):

you tried? #contentSection height

```
$("#contentSection").css("height", newHeight - 0 + "px");
```

to

```
$("#contentSection").css("height", newHeight+30 - 0 + "px");
```

Comment: First and foremost, pasting your above code edit into his jsfiddle doesn't fix it.  Furthermore, his problem lies in fundamental layout issues in his CSS & HTML.  Javascript should never be used to fix layout... 

http://jsfiddle.net/z0Lzeppj/7/

Comment: @Michael I dont answer before try. I tried and works well. Then only I posted here, replace the code wherever "$("#contentSection").css("height", newHeight - 0 + "px");" line occured. There are two line!

Comment: Updated my JSFiddle as you suggested, yet it is still not correct...http://jsfiddle.net/z0Lzeppj/8/

30PX is too much to move the box.  It should be just 15px...  And yet still, this really isnt something that should be fixed in jquery.  Rather, better HTML and CSS layout design should be implemented...http://jsfiddle.net/z0Lzeppj/9/

Comment: The question like border-bottom takes more spaces. show more border's bottom takes more space. My solution hide that unwanted space.

Comment: Yes, but it hides TOO MUCH of it, and it's a terrible way of doing it.  The solution should NOT be to add more javascript, but rather correct the errors in his CSS...  Fixing this with javascript is putting a patch over a hole in your boat.  Eventually, you are still going to sink until you fix the hole.